# Show DevExpress waitform dialog without designer

Tags: c#, winforms, dialog, devexpress

I'm trying to display a Loading Please Wait dialog form using devex controls and I can't seem to do it. (using winforms, c#)

I'm using an older version of devex - not the latest. I can't do

```
SplashScreenManager.ShowDefaultWaitForm()
```

I need to do this in code without the designer.

1.
I tried:

```
SplashScreenManager.ShowForm(typeof(WaitDialogForm));
```

It looks right when it loads, but then it throws an error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'DevExpress.Utils.WaitDialogForm' to type 'DevExpress.XtraSplashForm.SplashFormBase'

2. I tried:

   ```
   SplashScreenManager.ShowForm(typeof(WaitForm));
   ```

   This shows an empty form thats too big with no image and no text
3. I tried:

   ```
   WaitDialogForm mWaitDialog = new WaitDialogForm() {Visible = false};
   mWaitDialog.Show();
   ```

The wait form doesn't look right. There are white spaces instead of the image.

4. I tried:

   ```
   WaitDialogForm mWaitDialog = new WaitDialogForm() {Visible = false};
   mWaitDialog.ShowDialog();
   ```

The code doesn't continue executing.

5. I saw examples of

   ```
   SplashScreenManager.ShowForm(typeof(WaitForm1));
   ```

   I don't know how to do this without designer.

Can somebody please assist? I thought I'm doing something simple, but I can't seem to figure it out!

Comment: What exact version of DevExpress are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Probably this help u ;)

```
using (new DevExpress.Utils.WaitDialogForm("Please wait"))
{
 //Do your stuff here
}
```

Comment: No thanks. Not what I need. I need something that is displaying while form loads behind it and disappears when form finishes loading

Comment: I missunderstood your question. See the edited answer

Comment: no - not what i need. I need a form that is diaplayed while form loads in the front. form will be loading and when its finished loading, the front form fades out. thanks for trying.

Comment: much better. This is looking like what I need, but it has a very old fashioned look. Can the image be more current?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is in your 13.2 version but from looking at [documentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraSplashScreenSplashScreenManagerMembersTopicAll) you should be using ShowWaitForm instead of just ShowForm.

```
SplashScreenManager ssm = new SplashScreenManager();
ssm.ActiveSplashFormTypeInfo = typeof(WaitForm1);
ssm.ShowWaitForm();
```

If that does not work then i would just try *preparing* a working solution in the designer and then extracting the code from the designer.cs file.

Found a specific documentation example [here](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument10824)